# How do I pass php variables and textarea values using a href?

Tags: php, html, href

I have some variables stored using php and an html textarea.  I would like the value from the textarea (whatever user types in) to be stored in a variable $options and pass all of the variables from the same page using .  I am getting stuck on how to combine the value from the textarea with the php variables' values.  This is the code I have so far:

```
$price = $_GET['price'];
$title = $_GET['title'];
$retailer = $_GET['retailer'];

<textarea rows="3" id="textarea" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Size, color, style, etc" name ="options"></textarea>

<a href = "viewcart.php?retailer=<?php echo $retailer?>" class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i>  Add to Cart</a>
```

How do I combine the three variables together?

Comment: You'll need to use a little javascript most likely... (since PHP has the sent variables, but javascript will need to dynamically fetch the user's input and add it to the URL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Use this code, you have to add some javascript code to get value of text area.

```
$price = $_GET['price'];
$title = $_GET['title'];
$retailer = $_GET['retailer'];

<textarea rows="3" id="textarea" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Size, color, style, etc" name ="options"></textarea>

<script language="javascript">
function test()
{
    var val=document.getElementById("textarea").value;  
    var hrf="viewcart.php?retailer=<?php echo $retailer?>&price=<?php echo $price; ?>&title=<?php echo $title; ?>&option="+val;
    document.getElementById("a_link").href=hrf;
}
</script>
<a href ="#" id="a_link" onclick="test();" class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i>  Add to Cart</a>
```

Update your code with my code and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<a href = "viewcart.php?retailer=<?php echo $retailer?>&title=<?php echo $title?>&price=<?php echo $price?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write down a java script code just like on button click or what ever suits you the best and then you should store all these values in javascript variables. Text area value you can get by document.getElementById() method and for PHP values you can asign these values like

```
price = "<?php echo $_GET['price']?>"
```

inside javascript and so on. Then you can generate a query string which you can either append to your heref or you can directly use window.loaction and append that query string to url.